# How to use multiple handlers in jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code I am working on and I cannot seem to figure out the terms to search for assistance.

I am trying to add a jquery statement that executes when the #quickSearchResults_section is clicked "AND" when #nav-input is focused out.

So in a nutshell, I am still learning jquery and programming logic and want to use click function and focusout.

```
<script>
    $(":not(#quickSearchResults_section)").click(function(){
        $("#quickSearchResults_section").hide();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why the :not? Aren't you trying to add a listener when #quickSearchResults_section is clicked?

Comment: Yes, I want to hide an entire section with the id #quickSearchResults_section if you click out of the section with the only exception of staying open if the text input (#nav-input) is focused or active. I am probably wrong but looking for the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$("#nav-input").on("blur", function(){
    $("#quickSearchResults_section").click(function(){
        $("#quickSearchResults_section").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: This wont/didnt work as I need hide the code when the there is a click outside of the #quickSearchResults_section OR outside of the #nav-input